# "Opinion based" link should go to the "Don't Ask" page

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, help-center, opinion-based

Logically enough, the close banner for the "needs debugging details" close reason links to the [page on how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

However, the "Opinion Based" close banner links to the [generic Help Center page on why questions are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

In my opinion (joke intended), it makes more sense to link to the ["Don't Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in this case. This page is much more informative regarding what we expect from subjective questions.

Can this be changed?

Answer (score 24):

How about we add a link to the Don't Ask page from the questions closed page? This is what is being done right now for duplicate questions, as the point explaining for duplicates states this:

> **Duplicate** - The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. There’s more information in our [help center article about duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

So we could rewrite the Opinion Based point to look something like this:

> **Opinion-based** - Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great, but they just don't fit our format well. You can understand better which type of subjective questions are to be avoided in our help center article ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: "Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great, but they just don't fit our format well" seems a little indirect. "Opinion-based discussions don't fit our format well" seems more to the point, without making concessions. If not going all the way, I'd at least avoid using "just", which doesn't add value.

Comment: @ggorlen "Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great" is the kind of phrasing that people come up with when they are overly concerned with appearing to have the right political views.

Comment: Just a disclaimer, that this is the [current phrasing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) used in the Don't ask page, and I've just added the second phrase "You can understand better which type of subjective questions are to be avoided in our help center article "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". If we need to review that first phrase, that's a different topic